# Is it possible to pre populate text field based on some text field in visual flow in salesforce?

Tags: community, visual-flows

I have a requirement to pre-populate a text field based on another text field in visual flows in salesforce. Can we do this with the help of visual flow in salesforce?

Comment: How do you initiate the flow?

Comment: from a button present on detail record of a page

Comment: Then you can pass parameter through flow url

Comment: but that text field is present on same flow on which another text field is present and based on that I need to update other field. How the parameter through flow will update that text box